# which is the best way to store default values for Firebase Remote Config?

Tags: android, firebase-remote-config

the people suggest using the .xml file like:

```
<entry>
    <key>onboarding_enabled</key>
    <value>false</value>
</entry>
```

but i already have values stored in the BaseActivity like:

```
public boolean onboarding_enabled = false;
```

then in onCreate() method:

```
onboarding_enabled = remoteConfig.getBoolean("onboarding_enabled");
```

what i prefer is keep the values but in onCreate method call the remote config. is it gonna work like this? is it better way to store default values?

Answer (score 1):

The way to set default parameter values from XML file is Google's [official instruction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/get-started?platform=android#set-in-app-default-parameter-values). I would follow that.

The reason, I guess, your way to define a variable's default is not preferable is that these [`FirebaseRemoteConfig#getBoolean`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig#public-boolean-getboolean-string-key), [`#getDouble`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig#public-double-getdouble-string-key), [`#getLong`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig#public-long-getlong-string-key) or  [`#getString`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig#public-string-getstring-string-key), they **always** return values anyway. So, that is, your default value -- pre-defined at declaration -- will never be used.

For example `FirebaseRemoteConfig#getBoolean` states:

> Evaluates the value of the parameter in the following order:
>
> 1. The activated value, if the last successful `activate()` contained the key, and the value can be converted into a boolean.
> 2. The default value, if the key was set with `setDefaultsAsync`, and the value can be converted into a boolean.
> 3. `DEFAULT_VALUE_FOR_BOOLEAN`.

If your FireBaseRemoteConfig has not fetched config value via network yet, it uses at first the value defined in XML file, if XML is unavailable, it uses `DEFAULT_VALUE_FOR_BOOLEAN` (= `false`) for the second choice. There is no room to be used for your pre-defined value.